# How to convert C++ object to Python object use Cython?

Tags: python, c++, cython

**I would like to know how Python convert C++ object of custom class to Python object. Do I need to do anything with the Message class?**

*Message is a custom class contained in streaming. h*

**File: test.h**

```
#include "Streaming.h" //Definition of class Message

vector<Message> subscribe_(string taskid){
     vector<Message> vecMsg;
     
     ...
     
     
     return vecMsg;
}
```

**File: Streaming_test.pyx**

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.string cimport string


cdef extern from "Streaming.h":
    cdef cppclass Message:
        Message() except +
        
cdef extern from "test.h":
    vector[Message] subscribe_(const string taskid) nogil


def __subscribe(string taskid):
    cdef vector[Message] vecMsg
    listMsg = []

    vecMsg = subscribe_(taskid)

    for i in range(vecMsg.size()):
        listMsg.append(vecMsg[i])
    return listMsg
```

**File:setup.py**

```
#build: python setup.py build_ext --inplace
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize 

ext = Extension("wrapper_streaming",
                sources = ["streaming_test.pyx"],
                language = "c++",
                library_dirs = ["../../build"],
                libraries = ["DolphinDBAPI","pthread","ssl","rt"],
                include_dirs = ["/root/api-cplusplus/include"],
                extra_compile_args = ["-std=c++11"]
                )

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(ext, language_level = 3))
```

**The error that occurs when I try to compile this:**

```
    vecMsg = subscribe_(taskid)
    for i in range(vecMsg.size()):
        listMsg.append(vecMsg[i])
                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

streaming_test.pyx:115:23: Cannot convert 'Message &' to Python object
```

How to convert Message type objects into Python objects?
Message is a custom class contained in streaming. h

Answer (score -1):

To convert a C++ object to a Python object using Cython, you can create a Cython extension module that defines Python wrapper classes for your C++ objects and implements the necessary conversion functions.

Comment: can you please show an example of how to achieve this based on the code shown in the question post?